# why isnt my for i in range loop repeating, and running the functionseveral timez and then printing the results

Tags: python, for-loop, range, nested-for-loop

My program checks if the first element in the list is an h, if it is then it changes the t to h and h to t, that all works, then it deletes the first element in the list, that works, but why is it not repeating all this code and functions for I in range y times, it only does it once but I want it to do it 3 times, I have tried moving the pop and print function to different positions in the nested loops, but that does not work

```py
x, y=map(int, input().split())
    p=list(map(str, input().split()))
    for i in range(int(y)):
        if p[0]=='H':
            for i in range(int(x)):
                if p[i]=='H':
                    p[i]='T'
                else:
                    p[i]='H'
            else:
                continue
            p.pop(0)
        print(p)
```

Comment: If I put a `print` underneath `for i in range(int(y)):`, then it shows that that block is run `y` times. What is the purpose of the `continue` under the `else`? Because you don't have a `break` anywhere in the `for`-loop above it, you never reach the `pop` or `print` statements.

Comment: Show the input and expected output, please.

Comment: how would i break out of the for loop